# Groovy Invoke Map.variableName expecting variableName to be replaced with corressponding value NOT working

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a groovy script code,

```
result  = new JsonSlurper().parse(<URL object>.newReader())
echo $result.propertykey
```

> Note : result is a Map which contains multiple key value pairs including
> propertykey1:propertyvalue1

**Output :**

'*propertyvalue1*' value is printed as expected.

I have written a method which will take different propertykey as input parameter (parameter name : propertykeyNameparam)

When I write echo result.$propertykeyNameparam I am expecting it to replace propertykeyNameparam with propertykey1 so it becomes result.propertykey1 and finally print propertyvalue1.

```
get_propertyvalue(propertykey1)
...
...
...
def get_propertyvalue(propertykeyparam) {
  result  = new JsonSlurper().parse(<URL object>.newReader())
  echo $result.propertykeyNameparam
  echo "result.$propertykeyNameparam"
  echo $result.$propertykeyNameparam
}
```

**Issue :**

echo $result.propertykeyNameparam            <---- This line prints **null**.

echo "result.$propertykeyNameparam"          <---- This line prints **result.branch**

echo $result.$propertykeyNameparam           <---- This line prints whole result_Map.propertykeyNameparam

Expected output:

```
                   propertyvalue1
```

Comment: `echo result.propertykeyNameparam` should work. or `echo "${result.propertykeyNameparam}"`

Comment: you need to add `$` only inside the doublequoted string

Comment: echo result.propertykeyNameparam

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet solved my issue

```
for (entry in result) {
    if (entry.key == propertykey1)
    {
        echo "$entry.value"
    }
}
```